# Powershell Timestamp Transcript

Tags: powershell, timestamp, transcription

Due to a restricted enviroment I want to run plink (Putty) within Powershell to generate a time-stamped transcript of the Powershell/plink session.

I can't see a timestamp option within the native powershell. What is the best way of doing this?

I have considered using Tee, but since plink is not a PS object I am not sure I can.

Comment: from what i can tell, there is no built in way to explicitly generate a file name with a timestamp. you can make one via code with `$TimeStamp = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss' ... and then use that to build your file name.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I was not referring to a file bame, but the file logging of each command/receipt. I was wondering if I can monitor the file for a newline and append a Timestamp dynamically?

Comment: the `Get-Content` cmdlet has a parameter that seems to do part of what you want ... `Get-Help Get-Content -Parameter tail`. however, appending a timestamp to a line in an active file sounds like a formula for lock collisions. you would likely be safer to read the source file, create a timestamped line, and then write that to an entirely different file.